# NPM not finding packages in http://registry.npmjs.org, on Mac only

Tags: macos, npm

I have been working on a Mac now for over a year and had to get back to some Node.js work.  As I try to install packages using NPM (e.g. `npm install -g apiconnect`, npm install @cloudnative/health-connect`)

I get a 404 error while installing dependent packages, stating that the package in Not Found. e.g.

```
Npm install -g apiconnect

... installs a bunch of packages

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/@kyleshockey%2fjs-yaml - Not Found
```

However, using `curl http://registry.npmjs.org/@kyleshockey%2fjs-yaml` it is found with no problem.

I am currently running NPM v6.9.0 and Node v10.13.0.

I have checked my configuration and it looks valid.

```
npm config get registry

<returns>
http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I have tried `npm cache clean --force`, but get the same issue.

I have also tried changing the registry to use https:// instead of http://

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Same error.  Also, the error is not all or nothing. While building my node environment, I installed the Angular CLI, and this installed without a problem.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Finally, I have tried everything with my VPN on and off.

I am at a loss for what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the tar gzipped file from https://github.com/shockey/js-yaml-browser/releases/tag/1.0.1

And then do `npm i <filepath>` to install the npm dependency manually.